# Options for math equations rendering in WP in own server

Tags: plugins, plugin-mathjax

I would like to write an article for a WP-site and include math equations. The site is hosted on own/rented servers (i.e. site is not a free or paid WP-blog).

The owners of the site are not technical and have no idea how to setup this but can follow simple instructions if needed. I have no admin rights on their server whatsoever and I do not want to have.

Firstly, I am looking to what choice there is out there for a way to do this in a free, open way which does not injects advertisement, places cookies on users, or monitors users across sites, or whatever other corporate practice which is not considered kosher for at least 99% of internet users.

For example, I would prefer that the processing-burden to be minimal, to  use local cache for example (for the rendered images). But I would scream with horror on suggestions for 3rd-party servers to render and store said images and viewers of the article to load math-equation images from this 3rd-party server. That screams horror on its own.

Secondly, please include some instructions/links on how to set this up for non-technical people.

I have read of some options, like Jetpack, but it is still unclear to me about my first request: local cache, avoid 3rd-party servers, 3rd-party cookies and 3rd-party cross-site monitoring. Also, expressiveness and power, e.g. having microsoft equation quality is not what I am looking for. On the other hand LATEX will be the ultimate cure (WP+LATEX=L.F.E.)

Has anyone out there written the definite guide/comparison for math rendering options on WP-based sites?

P.S. it seems there are no appropriate SO tags for this post: e.g. mathematical-equations-rendering. Or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way for everyone involved is probably using [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), if I'm not mistaken, this is also used on the Math StackExchange sites.

Searching the WordPress Plugin Repository I found [MathJax-LaTeX](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/#description) and [Simple Mathjax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mathjax/) as well as other plugins.

Try those out, read the reviews, etc. and decide which to use on the site. The difference shouldn't be too great. This will allow you to place code beautiful via

```
[latex]a^2 + b^2 = c^2[/latex]
$$ v = s \times a $$
$ 2 \times 3 = 9 $
```

Comment: Any comments about equation images kept in 3rd-party servers and cookies?

Comment: @bliako Images are probably generated on the client via JS, well and for cookies you can check their privacy sites. If you want something simple to use AND have specific privacy needs, you'll have problems. You'd need some special PHP modules, not sure if the hoster provides this for you already